# Yii: CHtml:link with an image and div

Tags: php, hyperlink, yii

How do I create a link with an `image` and `div` together in yii.

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="uploads/image.jpg" title="sports" />
    <div class="media-title mosaic-overlay">
        <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->evntcatm_name), array('view', 'id'=>$data->evntcatm_name)); ?>
    </div>
</a>
```

Right now, I have given link to `text` only, I want to give link to image and div together.

Comment: I don't know Chtml but after document is ready you can use javascript and assign onlick command to a tag which is surrounding img and div tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('view', array('id' => $data->evntcatm_name))?>">
    <img src="uploads/image.jpg" title="sports" />
    <div class="media-title mosaic-overlay">
        <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->evntcatm_name) ?>
    </div>
</a>
```